# Why isn't my IPv6 address changing with privacy extension enabled?

Tags: ipv6

My `/etc/issue` says that I'm working with Debian GNU/Linux 11 on my RPi.

I have enabled IPv6 and I received a Link-local address that was a derivative of the MAC address. After that, I put `slaac private` in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` so that the privacy extension is activated (I took inspiration from [this article](https://kalitut.com/raspberry-pi-ipv6-privacy-extensions/)). After a reboot the Link-local address has changed and I was not able to find similarities with the MAC address anymore (as it should).

My problem is that after a second reboot, I was expecting that the address should have changed again (for privacy's sake) but it remains the same. I have read [there](https://superuser.com/questions/793175/behavior-of-ipv6-privacy-extensions) that the address should change after unplugging the cable. So I try but when I put the plug back, the address was still the same.

Did I miss something or is there an issue ?

Thank you,

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

You have provided no evidence.

`slaac private` is the default - and extremely annoying IMO as it keeps adding new entries to known_hosts - so I turn it OFF!

NOTE `slaac private` DOES NOT guarantee that it will change.

What it actually does is "generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses based from the DUID"